# What do higher order diffusion terms do?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, intuition, heat-equation

I have been trying to learn to work with the Python module [FiPy](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/), which is supposed to solve PDEs of the form
$$
\frac {\partial(\rho \phi)} {\partial t} - [\nabla\cdot(\Gamma_i\nabla)]^n\phi - \nabla \cdot({\bf u} \phi)=S_\phi.
$$
The most important term for me is the diffusion term with $[\nabla\cdot(\Gamma_i\nabla)]^n\phi$. This is where I got the inspiration for this question.

Diffusion equations (at least those I know of) involve only the Laplacian (i. e., $n=1$). The archetypal heat equation, $\nabla^2 \phi = \phi_t$, can simply be understood as a smoothing process - the Laplacian gives the "local average", towards which the function tends.

However, I have no idea how to interpret higher-order diffusion terms or why they might be useful. For example, does a fourth-order term $\nabla^4 \phi$ also give rise to a smoothing process? How is this different to what $\nabla^2 \phi$ does?

The only application of fourth-order PDEs I know of is the beam equation, $\nabla^4 \phi = \phi_{tt}$. This is a form of the wave equation rather then the diffusion equation, but it's the closest I could find. The beam equation does indeed behave similarly to the wave equation, but the eigenvalues are different - is some similar effect seen in the diffusion equations?

Answer (score 3):

An essential consequence of the appearance of fourth (or higher) order terms in the diffusion equation is the breakdown of the [maximum principle:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) in the second order equation an initially positive state will stay positive, but this is no  longer guaranteed if you include higher order derivatives. You need the maximum principle if you want the variable to represent a physical quantity that is inherently positive, such as a density or temperature.

The appearance of a fourth order term is particularly interesting and relevant if you also include nonlinearities, such as the [Swift–Hohenberg equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift%E2%80%93Hohenberg_equation). The fourth order derivative then allows for chaotic dynamics.

In the context of image restoration, the smoothing effect of fourth order terms helps to make the image less "blocky" (fewer constant regions), see You and Kaveh's [Fourth-order partial differential quation for noise removal.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5589075_Fourth-order_partial_differential_equation_for_noise_removal)